# How to get count from two columns in django queryset?

Tags: python, django

**models.py**

```
class Friend(models.Model):
    creator = models.ForeignKey(Individual, related_name="friendship_creator_set", blank=True, null=True)
    friend = models.ForeignKey(Individual, related_name="friend_set", blank=True, null=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=False, blank=True)
    confirm = models.BooleanField(default=False, blank=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    modified_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)
```

I am adding this two query to get the result:

```
Friend.objects.filter(creator_id=value, confirm=True).count() + Friend.objects.filter(friend_id=value, confirm=True).count()
```

How can convert it to a single queryset in Django?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to do an or condition..

```
from django.db.models import Q
Friend.objects.filter(Q(creator_id=value) | Q(friend_id=value), confirm=True).count()
```